# Is SQL Injection possible in String Concatenation When all Variables are created by the Program

Tags: javascript, sql-injection

Say I have a program that returns some date strings from a function in javascript.

```
function getDates()
{
    var yesterday = [some code that gets current time with yesterday's date];
    var today = [some code that gets today's time and date];
    return [yesterday.toSomeDBStorageStringFormat, today.toSomeDBStorageStringFormat];
}
```

Then, say that I get these values and plug them into a SQL statement.

```
function calledByUserViaWebAPI()
{
    var dates = getDates();
    var response = queryDB('SELECT * FROM Table T WHERE T.Date BETWEEN ' + dates[0] + ' AND ' + dates[1] + ';');
    return response;
}
```

Is this SQL query in any way vulnerable? Say that a user calls the `calledByUserViaWebAPI` function.

Comment: Where could a user inject anything?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. A SAST scan would pick this up as insecure, but I'm wanting to know whether it is a false positive in this case, or if there is some way a user could still affect one of the variables.

Comment: Can a user call `calledByUserViaWebAPI.dates`?

Comment: If the user can inject date, can you please validate the input for date format?

Comment: Something like this (untested) :  SELECT * FROM Table T WHERE T.Date BETWEEN  + ''1/1/1910' AND '1/1/1910'; IF (1=1)'' + ' AND ' + '(1=1) SELECT 1; DROP TABLE Table' + ';');

Comment: Only string variables can open the door to sql injection. Date datatypes are safe. Parse a date string then format as iso date string. You sanitise the string, and you limit date culture bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it currently vulnerable? **No**.

Should you change it anyway? **Probably**

If you are putting variables in an SQL query then you should use prepared queries. They make almost no impact on your code base and usually have only a tiny impact on performance. As a result, the cost of using prepared queries is small. Obviously you would ask "But there is no vulnerability here so why should I take the time to change it?". The answer is simple: **you never know how your code will change later**

What if down the road management decides they want to let users select the date range themselves? A hurried programmer updates the `getDates` method to return the input from the user and performs no validation on it (the programmer is in a rush after all, and doesn't think to check everywhere and see how the return value is used).

Now you do have an SQL vulnerability. It may seem like a stretch, but many security weaknesses happen as a result of small incremental code changes where someone coming in later no longer remembers the full context of the code in question. As a result, my rule of thumb is that as long as the prepared query is easy to put in with minimal performance issues then use prepared queries for your variables  even if it (currently) seems unnecessary.

Also, I think it is better to be in the habit of using prepared queries and only skipping them after careful consideration, rather than being in the habit of skipping prepared queries and only **using** them after careful consideration. The later habit will generate many more security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Injection requires data that an attacker can control - for your example I am assuming this is a client-server setup with the code executing on the server.

Its not injectable unless the functions process is using something that user provides directly or indirectly (lets say culture string or something).

Your example has the input is completely controlled by the application and host (assuming data information comes from the host) so there is no vector for injection or tampering, unless someone changes the host date.

Yes SAST will detect this as an issue - but SAST is only as good as the rules written and most SAST rules are very simple & limited, not evening inspecting outside a function scope. Those rules will not have the smarts to inspect where data is coming.